# Xcode Export -> Save for Mac App Store Deployment

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to test my OS X application in cloud kit production environment. One Apple Engineer recommended that I test it by archiving then exporting it with the "Save For Mac App Store Deployment" option.
So I did, then ran the package installer, but when I try to run the app it crashes with code signature invalid.

I've made sure that when I archive the app before exporting, It is set to Release "mode" and that the provisioning profile is the mac app store distribution.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: go to Terminal and type in "`codesign --display --verbose=4 /path/to/Your.app`" (i.e. use the path to your app in that last bit there) and do you see it properly codesigned?

Comment: @the Reverend Did you figure out the issue here? I face the same thing.

Comment: Up until now, there is now way to test the production environment in  an OS X application.